# How to create a step function that iterates over a list of strings

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to create my first AWS step function. I needs to iterated over a list of string and pass each value to a lambda function. I've gotten started but I'm not understanding how to reference the current element in the list to pass was parameter to the lambda function.

```json
{
  "StartAt": "Handle Loaders",
  "States": {
    "Handle Loaders": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemsPath": "$.InputData"
      "Iterator": {
        "StartAt": "Execute Loader"
        "Execute Loader": {
          "Type": "Task"
          "Resource": !Ref DataLoader,
          "Parameters": {
            "SeedData": <same for every iteration> 
            "Loader": <the current string iterated over>
          }
          "End": true
        }
      }
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

I imagine the input would looks something like this

```json
{
  "InputData: {
    "SeedData": <somedata_values>,
    "Loaders": ["Makes", "Models", "Styles"],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the definition that you are looking for:

```
{
  "StartAt": "Handle Loaders",
  "States": {
    "Handle Loaders": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemsPath": "$.InputData.Loaders",
      "Parameters": {
        "loader.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value"
      },
      "Iterator": {
        "StartAt": "Execute Loader",
        "States": {
          "Execute Loader": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "<arn of your function>",
            "Parameters": {
              "SeedData.$": "$$.Execution.Input.InputData.SeedData",
              "Loader.$": "$.loader"
            },
            "End": true
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Here are some useful link that would help you to understand it:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-input-output-filtering.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html

Also, given that you are starting with step functions I'd recommend you 2 useful tools in the console:

- [Data Flow Simulator](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/04/aws-step-functions-adds-new-data-flow-simulator-for-modelling-input-and-output-processing/)
- [Workflow Studio](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-step-functions-workflow-studio-a-low-code-visual-tool-for-building-state-machines/)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a part of the definition for moving into the tasks inside the Map:

```
Iterator": {
"StartAt": "Prepare Test Data",
    "States": {
      "Prepare Test Data": {
        "Type": "Task",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
        "OutputPath": "$.TestData",
        "Parameters": {
          "Payload.$": "$",
          "FunctionName": "arn:aws:your:function"
        },
        "Next": "Call_Test_System
      },
      "Call_Test_System::{
         "Type": "Task", 
         ... ect
```

specifically note that after StartAt key, there is a key States: that is the mini definition of tasks/states within a map iterator.

You can then use the OutputPath defined (in this case as the base of the json `$` under the key `TestData`

in an InputPath for the next step in the same format, which will pass whatever the first state outputs into the next.

The Iterator also has an OutputPath, where it will place a *list* of all the responses of the iterations within the map.